# String difference php

Tags: php

I want to create a method which compares two sentence and returns the words that makes them different.

e.g

grey tiles 100 X 200 kitchen flooring

grey tiles 300 X 600 kitchen flooring

difference are
100 x 200
300 x 600

it will allow one single word (not necesary one character to sit between two unique words)
though if the distance exceeds by one it will throw an error saying the phrases are not similar enough
the difference can be found at the start/ end /  middle  of the text

after passing to different blogs, i found similar approach to my concern using the native php function xdiff_string_diff but the problem is, I cant make the code works. I got error saying xdiff_string_diff is undefined function.
Anyone of you knows what extensions should be loaded to make this function available?
Or if you can suggest another approach it will be great and much appreciated. :)

```
<?php
$old_article = "grey tiles 100 X 200 kitchen flooring";
$new_article = "grey tiles 300 X 600 kitchen flooring"

$diff = xdiff_string_diff($old_article, $new_article, 1);
if (is_string($diff)) {
    echo "Differences between two articles:\n";
    echo $diff;
}

?>
```

Comment: xdiff is not a native library.

Comment: For you consideration: 100 x 200 / 300x 600 is NOT the difference. The difference is 100 x 2 / 300 x 6. Both stings have ... 00 kitchen ... in common!

Answer (score 7):

You will have to install xdiff

```
pecl install  xdiff
```

Alternatively you could try using array_diff to find differences between the strings. Explode them on space and then array_diff them:

```
$a1 = explode(" " , 'grey tiles 100 X 200 kitchen flooring');
$a2 = explode(" ", 'grey tiles 300 X 600 kitchen flooring');

echo join(' ', array_diff($a1, $a2)); // 100 200
```

This will not catch the X though, as the X is going to be the common part of the string in that context.

Comment: nahh i lost my appetite to xdiff. maybe we can have another approach.

Comment: nah, the thing is when using array_diff is the compare words regardless of its position. which is for me its not relevant. maybe its better to loop every single index in the original sentence array

Answer (score 2):

On every manual page of every function (or library) it always mentions if it's shipped with PHP by default or not and from what version of PHP they started packing it into the release.

If it's not in the release then it mentions the package it's in (either PECL or PEAR).

O [its](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) manual page it states:

```
PECL xdiff >= 0.2.0
```

If you're running BSD/Solaris/Linux/Mac all you have to do is open a console and type in:

```
pear install xdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each character one by one, in every difference you can increase a counter by one. But this solution will not give you "300", it will give you 3.

Comment: The question is not about how to compare strings but about weather the `xdiff` packaged is installed.

Comment: but @user1065261 says "if you can suggest another approach it will be great and much appreciated."

Comment: any suggestions is much appreciated. well i can split every word and put an index to them, and we can have a loop to each index and compare the words. been in this solutions using array_intersect and array_diff but i dont know, for me im not satisfied with this solutions. this is good for few words only, what if we have a very long sentence. for sure wel going to have lots of index in the array which is very waste of memory