# xdiff_string_diff() function returning fatal error

Tags: php

I am trying to find diffrence between old and new strings using `xdiff_string_diff()` function like the following :

```
$old_str="Hello world";
$edited_str="Hello ladies!";
echo xdiff_string_diff($old_str,$edited_str,1);
```

My server is returning a fatal error :

```
Call to an undefined function
```

My php version is 5.4*

What could the problem be?

Do I need to install something on my server to get this function to work?

Please help!

Comment: you need to install `xdiff`. Type `pear install xdiff` in your console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String difference php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002132/string-difference-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to install `xdiff`

```
pecl install  xdiff
```

or tou can try this:

```
$a1 = explode(" " , 'Hello world');
$a2 = explode(" ", 'Hello ladies!');

echo join(' ', array_diff($a1, $a2)); // output :- world
```

Comment: i only signin to vote this, really simple function but powerfull. You are awesome man!!